# Where it is better to make a request (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

First request return for me two lists: `list1`, `list2`.
So i need render `list1` immediately. But for `list2` i need to check from second request and then display him. Where better place to do that?

p.s. now i am doing that in `componentDidMount` in item of `list2`. isChecking - set true when request is ending and give result.

```
const Container = (props) => <div>
    {props.list1.map(item => <Item {...item} />)}
    {props.list2.map(item => <Item {...item} check={true}/>)}
</div>;

class Item extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      if (check) {
        this.props.checkRequest();
      }
    }

    render() {
      if (this.props.check && !this.props.isChecking) {
        return <span />;
      }

      return <div>{item.name}</div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the checking logic for the `list1` you can directly map it without using `Item` component for it, like this:

```
const Container = (props) => <div>
    {props.list1.map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>)} // <------- no Item component here
    {props.list2.map(item => <Item {...item} check={true}/>)}
</div>;

class Item extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      if (check) {
        this.props.checkRequest();
      }
    }

    render() {
      if (this.props.check && !this.props.isChecking) {
        return <span />;
      }

      return <div>{item.name}</div>;
    }
}
```